# How to deploy one .war after another on JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, war

Is there a way to define order of .war deployments on JBoss 7? 
What I would like to accomplish is that on startup of JBoss it first deploys .war A and then .war B.

I need this because .war A is a service which is consumed on a startup of .war B!

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the dependency on the B war by creating a `jboss-all.xml` file on the `META-INF` folder,with a content like this:

```
 <jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
  <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
    <dependency name="A.war" />
  </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

The procedure is explained here [Control the order of Deployed Applications on JBoss](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Control_the_order_of_Deployed_Applications_on_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform.html)

Comment: I did try that, and it doesn't work. If the application A.war is not enabled application B.war still tries to start and fails because context of B.war is not found...

Comment: It's a web app? If so, you have to place the `jboss-all.xml` file into the `WEB-INF` folder instead of `META-INF`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/249069?start=0&tstart=0) JBoss's Forum thread, in order to ensure that A.war is deployed first than B.war, you should create a *MANIFEST* file under your B.war's *src/main/webapp/META-INF* folder, with the following entry:

```
dependencies: deployment.A.war
```

Furthermore, if you need to access A.war classes from B.war, you should also add a *jboss-deployment-structure.xml*, under your B.war's *src/main/webapp/WEB-INF* folder, with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2 http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-deployment-structure-1_2.xsd">

    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.A.war" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

You can also take a look at JBoss AS 7 class loading [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Class+Loading+in+AS7).